# How to Find Out the Content of a Dictionary when Debugging in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

A familiar function. Now there is this attributeDict object.

I want to know what are all the keypairs in the object.

I go to expression window and see that it contain NSObject that contains a reference to ISA.

So what should I do? NSLog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select "Print Description" in the context (right click) menu. Or in the debug terminal window you can type `po variablename`. You can also, as you suggest, use `NSLog`.

Comment: I right click and I do not see any Print Description in context menu

Comment: It's there either when you click on the variable in the list in the debugger or when you hover over a variable in the code you (sometimes) get a widget to select.

Answer (score 4):

You can print contents of your dictionary to console, for example using NSLog in your code:

```
NSLog("%@", attributeDict);
```

Or while debugging place breakpoint in that method and type in debugger console:

```
po attributeDict
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSLog(@"%@",attributeDict);` to print out the dictionary content.

If, for example, you have set a breakpoint and you are in GDB console you can use `po attributeDict` that stand for print object and do the same thing as NSLog